# Angular material design not displaying plotly viz on any tabs other than the first one

Tags: typescript, user-interface, angular-material, httpclient, plotly.js

Context: I have a report component on my angular app, where I want to display plotly visuals on multiple tabs. Data is sourced from the database using an API call.

Problem: First tab is displaying the visual without any issue. All other tabs fails to display the visuals.

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No DOM element with id 'plot2' exists on the page.

All visuals working good, but only on 'Tab 1'. I tried using the Bootstrap, and is working well with the same code. Can I please get this issue resolved. The TypeScript and HTML codes are as below:

TypeScript code:

```
export class ReportsComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private patientService: PatientService,
    private plotly: PlotlyService,
  ){
    this.isLoading = true;
   }

  ngOnInit(): void { 
  this.getPlot();      
  }

  getPlot() {
       const sentStatus = this.patientService.getodata().subscribe(
       (response:any) => { 
          const data = response.value;   
 
          this.plotly.getPlotly().then((Plotly) => {
        // Column chart 
            const data1 = [ 
            ]; 
            const layout1 = { 
            };
            Plotly.newPlot('plot1', data1, layout1);

            // Time series plot
            const data2 = [  
            ];
            const layout2 = {       
            };
            Plotly.newPlot('plot2', data2, layout2);
          });  
          this.isLoading = false;
       }); 
  }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
      <!--Tab 1 content -->
      <div id="plot1"></div>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
      <!--Tab 2 content -->
      <div id="plot2"></div>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 3">
      <!--More Tabs-->
    </mat-tab>
 </mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading) of `mat-tab`:

> By default, the tab contents are eagerly loaded. Eagerly loaded tabs
> will initialize the child components but not inject them into the DOM
> until the tab is activated.
>
> If the tab contains several complex child components or the tab's
> contents rely on DOM calculations during initialization, it is advised
> to lazy load the tab's content.

It seems that plotly expects to have the DOM elements inserted (as per the exception you've pasted). Again, as per the above docs, you should place the body of the tab within `ng-template` and decorate the template with the `matTabContent` to lazy load the components, i.e. have the DOM inserted into the tabs, e.g.

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
      <!--Tab 1 content -->
      <ng-template matTabContent>
        <div id="plot1"></div>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
      <!--Tab 2 content -->
      <ng-template matTabContent>
        <div id="plot2"></div>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 3">
      <ng-template matTabContent>
        <div id="plot3"></div>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <!--More Tabs-->
 </mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Thank you. But it's not working that way for me.

Comment: Right. Try moving your `getPlot()` into `ngAfterViewInit`, which is called later on in the component lifecycle. If that doesn't help prepare an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on stackblitz.

Comment: With getPlot() in ngAfterViewInit the first tab is not displaying. Then I tried a combination of ngOninit and ngAfterViewInit by duplicating getPlot function with functions to call each tabs. This time both plots got displayed but there is a time delay for the second plot to pup up. I tried to call a third plot display function from ngAfterViewInit, but it didn'work. I wonder how I could display my third tab. I am happy working with Bootstrap that does not have any of these complications.